# Intellij Amend commit default to selected

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to default the Amend Commit check box in the intelliJ commit dialog box to selected ?

I always want to amend commit so I can avoid squashing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Also, it does not sound like it would be a good idea to implement. Why would you use amend so much?

You may raise this as a feature request on JB's you-track and explain your use-case in detail.